# csv.writer writing each character of word

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to export a list of names from the model, Locations. Locations has several objects containing a list of names, for example:

`['New York', 'Ohio', California'] ['New York', 'Chicago', California'] ['Miami', 'Ohio', California']`

The export function is as follows:

```
def export(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Location']) #header

    for launch in Location.objects.all().values_list('L_name'):
       export_data = zip_longest(*launch, fillvalue='')
       writer.writerows(export_data)

response['Content_Disposition'] = 'attatchment';
return response
```

Writerow is iterating on the characters of each name, producing a column of characters rather than names. Instead, I would like each name from each Location object in its own row, in the same column. The above example would result in nine rows.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: The blase answer would be: provide the correct input to `writer.writerows(...)` - you do not share what/how the data you try to write is structured or how `export_data` looks like. It should be a list of lists, each inner list is one row, each element of it one column of this row. Without data this is hard to answer. Please [edit] and add `export_data`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `writerows` expects a iterable, the rows. Each of these rows has then an iterable of columns. But here `export_data` is a single iterable. You furthermore do not need to use `zip_longest`, you can work with:

```
def export(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Location']) #header

    writer.writerows(Location.objects.values_list('L_name'))

    response['Content_Disposition'] = 'attachment';
    return response
```

or if `L_name` is a `ArrayField`, etc. you can unwind it with:

```
def export(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Location']) #header

    writer.writerows((x,) for xs in Location.objects.values_list('L_name')for x in xs)

    response['Content_Disposition'] = 'attachment';
    return response
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've edited my question, which I hope is clearer. This results in each list from the Locations object being written to one row, resulting in three rows of lists with several elements. I would like each element to appear in its own row. Going by my edited question, the solution would result in nine rows.

Comment: @RinaTse: what if you use `writer.writerows((x,) for xs in Location.objects.values_list('L_name')for x in xs)` instead?

Comment: @RinaTse: exactly *what* is `L_name`, an `ArrayField`?

Comment: I'm still getting three rows with a list of three names in each cell. The line,  export_data = zip_longest(*launch, fillvalue='') seemed to at least return the output vertically but for each character.

Comment: L_name stores several Location objects, each of which is a list of names. Your solution outputs each object (a list) onto one row. Instead, I'm trying to get each element of each list onto it's own row in one column.

Comment: @RinaTse: but then your field is a `CharField`, not an `ArrayFIeld` or something similar. Please don't do that. Reconstructing lists is tricky, especially if later you other types end up in the string.

Comment: The string will only ever consist of characters in this case but I get your point. I'll try this again with your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
def export(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Base']) #header

    for launch in Location.objects.all().values_list('L_name'):
        list_launch = list(launch)
        full_str = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in list_launch])
        str_split = ([full_str.split(",")])
        export_data = zip_longest(*str_split, fillvalue='')
        writer.writerows(export_data)

    response['Content_Disposition'] = 'attatchment';
    return response`
```

Converted the list into a string, split the string at the commas then used the line, zip_longest(*str_split, fillvalue='') to output each name vertically on its own row.